# Trying to install any package produces a lot of dependency errors

Tags: system-installation

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up php5-common (5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: error processing package php5-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-json:
 php5-json depends on phpapi-20131226; however:
  Package phpapi-20131226 is not installed.
  Package php5-common which provides phpapi-20131226 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-readline:
 php5-readline depends on phpapi-20131226; however:
  Package phpapi-20131226 is not installed.
  Package php5-common which provides phpapi-20131226 is not configured yet.
 php5-readline depends on php5-common (= 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cli:
 php5-cli depends on php5-common (= 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.
 php5-cli depends on php5-json; however:
  Package php5-json is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-common
 php5-json
 php5-readline
 php5-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if the php version that you are using is supported by the version on Ubuntu, if yes then you can use gdebi to install recursive packages